# Null Reference Exception when trying to upload a file via FTP

Tags: vb.net, ftp, nullreferenceexception

I made a FTP upload application, which changes the name of the file chosen in FileDialog to a set of variables from 4 ComboBoxes. But whenever i try to upload the file it says:
`Path Cannot be Null    Paramenter name: path`

in the immediate window it says:
`A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll`

and this:

[image: Path Error]

i've gone over the code multiple times but i do not understand what is wrong, since i am quite new to VB.

this is the code i used:

```
Dim Filename As String
    Dim originalFile As String

    Private Function enumerateCheckboxes(ByVal path As String)
        originalFile = path
        Dim fName As String
        For Each Control In Me.Controls
            If (TypeOf Control Is ComboBox AndAlso DirectCast(Control, ComboBox).SelectedIndex > -1) Then
                fName += CStr(Control.SelectedItem.Key) + "_"
            End If
        Next
        Try
            fName = path + fName.Substring(0, fName.Length - 1) + ".pdf"
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            MsgBox("Stack Trace: " & vbCrLf & ex.StackTrace)
        End Try
        Return fName
    End Function

    Public Function OpenDialog()
        Dim FD As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()

        FD.Title = "Selecteer een bestand"
        FD.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
        FD.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.*)|*.*"
        FD.FilterIndex = 2
        FD.RestoreDirectory = True

        If FD.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim Filename As String = FD.FileName
            Filename = StrReverse(Filename)
            Filename = Mid(Filename, InStr(Filename, "\"), Len(Filename))
            Filename = StrReverse(Filename)
            MsgBox(enumerateCheckboxes(Filename))
        End If
    End Function

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim request As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create("ip"), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
        request.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password")
        request.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile

        Dim file() As Byte

        Try
            Filename = OpenDialog()
            System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Filename)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            MessageBox.Show("Stack Trace: " & vbCrLf & ex.StackTrace)
        End Try

        FileSystem.Rename(originalFile, Filename)
        Dim strz As System.IO.Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
        strz.Write(file, 0, file.Length)
        strz.Close()
        strz.Dispose()
        FileSystem.Rename(Filename, originalFile)
    End Sub
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: `System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Filename)`: `Filename` is `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `ArgumentNullException` is not a `NullReferenceException`.  It's telling you the argument to one of the functions is `Nothing`.

It's being caused in part by these two lines:

```
Filename = OpenDialog()
System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Filename)
```

In this case, it appears that your `Filename` is `Nothing`, because `OpenDialog` doesn't return a value.  You'll need to return the file selected from the `OpenFileDialog`.

Comment: Oke, i see what i did wrong, but i dont understand completely how to fix this.

Add a return statement to OpenFileDialog(), But where?

Comment: Probably within this if statement: `If FD.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then`.  Any code after `Filename = OpenDialog()` that depends on a file having been selected should then get wrapped with an `If (Not Filename Is Nothing) Then`